# 'Request' object has no attribute 'get' Python error

Tags: python, query-string, flask

I am trying to get a url parameter in Python.

I am using this code:

```
from flask import request, url_for, redirect
# ...
controller = request.get('controller')
```

but I am getting this error:

```
'Request' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using a web framework?

Comment: What type is the `request` object?

Comment: I get request like this : from flask import request, url_for, redirect

Comment: Well, that is a good information, that it is Flask :-).

Comment: Sorry, I don't know Python at all. I'm trying to use this code in my aplication https://github.com/dailymotion/cloudkey-py/blob/master/examples/upload_html/upload.py

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You want to use [`request.args`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/?highlight=args#flask.Request) for your GET parameters in Flask.  Here is a quote with an example from the Accessing Request Data section of the [Quickstart](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/#accessing-request-data) document.

---

To access parameters submitted in the URL (?key=value) you can use the args attribute:

```
searchword = request.args.get('key', '')
```