# AttributeError: 'Request' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, web-services, flask

When i make a POST request to my server, i get a 500 ERROR with comment:

```
AttributeError: 'Request' object has no attribute 'get'
```

This is my server:

```
@app.route('/api/entries', methods = ['POST'])
def create_entry():
    if not request.json:
        abort(400)
    entry = {
        'id': entries[-1]['id'] + 1,
        'Title': request.get('Title', ""),
        'Description': request.get('Description', ""),
        'Info': request.get('Info', "")
    }
    entries.append(entry)
    return jsonify( { 'entry': entry } ), 201
```

here is also my entries array:

```
entries = [
    {
        'id': 1,
        'Title': 'baradum',
        'Description': 'desc 1', 
        'Info': 'info1',
    },
    {
        'id': 2,
        'Title': 'jasd',
        'Description': 'desc 2', 
        'Info': 'info 2',
    }
]
```

What causes the problem?

Comment: Are you sure that is the code you have, with the indentation as shown in your question?

Comment: This helped me.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10320307/request-object-has-no-attribute-get-python-error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just as i posted this question, i found the answer:

I needed to change

```
'Title': request.get('Title', ""),
```

to

```
'Title': request.json.get('Title', ""),
```