# Passing data from html to python using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax

Greeting everyone, I'm trying to pass json data from html to python, Im getting the data but the format is incorrect,

Below is my code

HTML

```
<select class="js-example-basic-multiple" id="Status" name="Status" multiple="multiple" style="display:inline-block;">
    {% comment %} <option value="ALL" checked="1">ALL</option> {% endcomment %}
    <option value="new">New</option>
    <option value="bid">Bid</option>
    <option value="inprogress">In Progress</option>
    <option value="onhold">On Hold</option>
    <option value="completed">Completed</option>
    <option value="archived">Archived</option>
</select>
```

javascript

```
$('#Status').change(function(){
    var selected_status = $('#Status').select2('val');
    var status_text = JSON.stringify(selected_status);
    $.ajax({
            url : '/dashboard/marketing/', // the endpoint
            type : 'GET', // http method
            data : { 'stat' : status_text,
                    'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{csrf_token}}'
                }, // data sent with the post request
            // handle a successful response
            success : function(data) {
            },
    });
});
```

view.py

```
stat = request.GET.getlist('stat')
    print(stat)
    for selected_status in stat:
        get_project_on_status = Project.objects.all().filter(project_stage=selected_status)
        for project in get_project_on_status:
            project_on_status_list.append(project)
```

The result I wanted is :

```
["new","bid","inprogress","onhold","completed"]
```

but what I'm getting is :

```
['["new","bid","inprogress","onhold","completed"]']
```

How can i remove the extra bracket? thanks!

Comment: You should pass it via post, not get. You asked your js to stringify the data, and it did.

Comment: Post your code!

Comment: Hi @Federico, thanks for the input, I'm changing it as we speak but can you show me a snippet of a proper code as well thanks.

Comment: hi @31piy i tried to send the value directly without stringify it, instead of  `'stat' : status_text` i used `'stat' : selected_status`  but now I'm not getting any value at all

Comment: Can you post the console.log for your selected_status variable?

Comment: Hi @VinodBhavnani this is the consolo.log for selected_status `["new", "bid", "inprogress", "completed"]`

Comment: @VinodBhavnani You can try this. ```import simplejson 
 simplejson.loads('["new","bid","inprogress","onhold","completed"]')```

Comment: Just remove the JSON.stringify line. And send the data as selected_status instead of status_text

Comment: And please use POST instead of GET

Comment: @VinodBhavnani -- there is nothing wrong in using `GET` here.

Comment: @VinodBhavnani i change it alraedy but for some weird reason if I change it to POST in not getting any value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know much about python, but you need to ensure that your values aren't stringified using `JSON.stringify`.

```
var status_text = selected_status; // Remove JSON.stringify from here

$.ajax({
  url : '/dashboard/marketing/', // the endpoint
  type : 'GET', // http method
  data : { 'stat' : status_text,
           'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{csrf_token}}'
         }, // data sent with the post request
  // handle a successful response
  success : function(data) {
  },
...
```

Also, jQuery automatically handles encoding of the data. So, the actual parameters name which is submitted to the server will be `stat[]`.

I think you will need to change the name of parameter to `stat[]` while retrieving the values on python side. Maybe, in this line:

```
stat = request.GET.getlist('stat[]')
```

For more details about how parameters are being sent, observe [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hh2famhv/).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23661276/attributeerror-request-object-has-no-attribute-get In case someone gets the same error as I do