# failed to retrieving data from response in python

Tags: python, flask

I have response object as `<Request 'http://xx.xx.xx.xx/pipelineInfo' [GET]>`and i am trying to get data from the request object as

```
request.json.get('xxx',NONE)
```

and also as

```
request.get('XXX',NONE)
```

but failed to get a response and getting an error as

> Exception : 'Request' object has no attribute 'get' and Exception : 'Request' object has no attribute 'json'.

Can someone suggest me what the issue will be?

Comment: You must initiate this header while sending data as json `Content-Type: application/json`

Comment: Actually i have working with one of the code provided by some other person.Currently i dont have contact with that person and even we dont know how data is sending by them and services written by them.onli i have an option to get the data from that.

Comment: Can you tell me how you are requesting this service? when you are getting this exception.

Comment: Try this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10320307/request-object-has-no-attribute-get-python-error

Comment: request.args.get is not giving error but giving none value

Answer (score 0):

you need use `args` property [reqcontext](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/reqcontext/)

```
request.args.get('XXX')
```

or [get_json](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.Request.get_json)

```
request.get_json().get('XXX')
```

Answer (score 0):

If the data sent in the request is json, you can use
`json_data = request.get_json()`

However,this function will return None if the mimetype is not application/json, but this can be overridden by the force parameter.

```
json_data = request.get_json(force=True)
```

An alternative way to get json data is:

```
json_data = json.loads(request.data) as well.
```

Other ways of getting data from request can be found in this question: [How to get data received in Flask request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10434599/how-to-get-data-received-in-flask-request)

Also, please do have a look at official documentation([http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.Request.get_json](http://Official%20doc))